# Are there differences between the different country's editions of Cards Against Humanity?

Tags: cards-against-humanity

Cards Against Humanity has different country editions, like UK, US, and AU.

Are there differences between these editions other than grammar? What are those differences?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I have both the US and the UK version. There are different cards in both editions. And there are cards with slightly different texts (for example Dear Abby in the US version and Dear Agony Aunt in the UK version).

And some names are different (Margaret Thatcher only appears in the UK version). The UK version also contains Scottish warriors lifting their kilts and pronouncing the names of Welsh towns.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.** Further to Toon Krijthe's answer, there are a number of cards that have been adjusted for cultural resonance, particularly with local stereotypes and common words..

The base games are freely available as PDFs to print an play (indeed, this is how the game gained popularity) on [their website](https://cardsagainsthumanity.com/). You can compare the [US edition](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cah/CAH_MainGame.pdf), [UK edition](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cah/CAH_MainGame_UK.pdf) and [Australian edition](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cah/CAH_MainGame_AU.pdf).

Below are the differences I've found, up to and including page 11. Probably some of these will show up later in the document in the other side, and some are just spelling changes, but they serve to illustrate the changes between the editions.

### WARNING - ADULT LANGUAGE WITHIN:

**Cards unique to the US edition:**

> Women in yogurt commercials.
>  
> Getting naked and watching Nickelodeon.
>  
> A bleached asshole.
>  
> Inserting a mason jar into my anus.
>  
> Court-ordered rehab.
>  
> Bingeing and purging.
>  
> The hardworking Mexican.
>  
> Boogers.
>  
> The Tempur-Pedic® Swedish Sleep System™.
>  
> Skeletor.
>  
> Figgy pudding.
>  
> Advice from a wise, old black man.
>  
> Five-Dollar Footlongs™.
>  
> Chunks of dead hitchhiker.
>  
> A ball of earwax, semen, and toenail clippings.
>  
> Dick Cheney.
>  
> The Amish.
>  
> The rhythms of Africa.
>  
> Pedophiles.
>  
> Sarah Palin.
>  
> Feeding Rosie O'Donnell.
>  
> Invading Poland.
>  
> Jobs.
>  
> The Boy Scouts of America.
>  
> The Care Bear Stare.
>  
> Mr. Clean, right behind you.
>  
> Jewish fraternities.
>  
> Hot Pockets®.
>  
> Judge Judy.
>  
> Robert Downey, Jr.
>  
> The Trail of Tears.
>  
> Friends with benefits.
>  
> The invisible hand.
>  
> All-you-can-eat shrimp for $4.99.
>  
> Heteronormativity.
>  
> The Patriarchy.
>  
> A sausage festival.
>  
> The chronic.
>  
> Fiery poops.
>  
> White-man scalps.
>  
> The morbidly obese.
>  
> GoGurt®.
>  
> Joe Biden.
>  
> Hip hop jewels.

**Cards unique to the UK edition:**

> Women in yoghurt adverts.
>  
> Getting naked and watching CBeebies.
>  
> A bleached arsehole.
>  
> Used knickers.
>  
> The bloody Welsh.
>  
> A Super Soaker™ full of cat piss.
>  
> Blowing up Parliament.
>  
> A Chelsea smile.
>  
> Waking up half-naked in a Little Chef car park.
>  
> Badger culling.
>  
> The sudden appearance of the Go Compare man.
>  
> Seeing Granny Naked.
>  
> Genuine human connection.
>  
> A ginger's freckled ballsack.
>  
> Some bloody peace and quiet.
>  
> Wiping her bum.
>  
> Doing a shit in Pudsey Bear's eyehole.
>  
> England.
>  
> Emma Watson.
>  
> My ex-wife.
>  
> A Fleshlight.
>  
> Madeleine McCann.
>  
> A sober Irishman who doesn't care for potatoes.
>  
> The North.
>  
> An entrenched class system.
>  
> Rubbing Boris Johnson's belly until he falls asleep.
>  
> The Hillsborough Disaster.
>  
> Ripping off the Beatles.
>  
> The end of days.
>  
> Establishing dominance.
>  
> Jedward.
>  
> A madman who lives in a police box and kidnaps women.
>  
> The Scouts.
>  
> The unstoppable tide of Islam.
>  
> Ed Balls.
>  
> Saying "I love you."
>  
> Millwall fans.
>  
> Holding down a child and farting all over him.
>  
> Penis breath.
>  
> Chivalry.
>  
> The cool, refreshing taste of Pepsi.®
>  
> Daniel Radcliffe's delicious arsehole.
>  
> Crumbs all over the bloody carpet.
>  
> Not wearing trousers.