# What is the difference between the AU and UK editions of Cards Against Humanity

Tags: cards-against-humanity

I just got the UK set and need to know which cards to add.  Would it be easier to tell me what cards are new/different to add?  Or what cards are identical to remove.

I want to know the difference between UK and AU editions.   Not the difference between UK and US editions

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games, this question is already asked at: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25622/are-there-differences-between-the-different-countrys-editions-of-cards-against.

Comment: That lists the difference between UK and US.  Im looking for the difference between UK and AU

Comment: @ToonKrijthe That's not fair to say. Two years ago you voted to delete an answer ON THAT QUESTION you just linked asking about AU version saying they should ask a new question. Which is it?

Comment: @corsiKa, that answer was deleted because it was another question.

Comment: @AdamDean, the question started as a difference between US & UK. But it is generalized later.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, there are only two answers there, one giving one example where an Aunt's name was changed.  The other an incomplete list of white cards unique to the US edition in relation to the UK edition and an incomplete list of white cards unique to the UK edition in relation to the US edition.  Some of those could be listed after page 11, after page 11 there could be more unique cards too.  There are no black cards mentioned or comparison to the AU edition

Comment: @AdamDean If you had a higher reputation you would see the other, deleted answer

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Yes, but the point was that person was asked to create a new question. This, years later from a different person, is that question. Why should it be closed now, especially when the question you linked does not answer this question? Unless you're proposing that the linked question become canonical?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe I only joined the site today after purchasing the edition today.  How could I possibly know that there is a deleted comment or the fact that I could see it with a higher reputation, whatever that means.

Comment: I didn't link anything, you did.  You put the link there telling me that the answer to my question is there, which it's not

Comment: All I did was ask the following question: What is the difference between the AU and UK editions of Cards Against Humanity?  You responded with two links to a similar question that didn't answer my question